# jpanel background magic numbers

Tags: java, magic-numbers

I don't want to use magic numbers. I'm setting a color to a jpanel background, Is there a possible way to use a color instead of

```
panel.setBackground(new color (255,255,255));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color class has **static** fields for most common colors. You can also define your own colors as constants and use them throughout your code.

```
Color myColor = new Color(1,2,3);
panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
panel.setBackground(myColor);
```

Comment: Why would you do that instead of just writing `panel.setBackground(Color.RED)` ?

Comment: @DavidWallace if it is used in many places it is shorter to write. it is a matter of preference.

Comment: If you really feel that the number of characters you have to type is an issue, then just use a static import, and write `panel.setBackground(RED);`.  There's no point in creating a brand new variable when one already exists.

Comment: @HashCoder if you have a new question, you should ask a new question, rather than slipping it in here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static fields of the Color class.

**Ex:-** [BLACK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#BLACK) , [WHITE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#WHITE)

```
panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```